# PHP submit blank screen - script not running on POST?

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I have a script that pulls an XML page and uses a form to update and save the values back. When I click the submit button it works, but then the page loads blank. I just want the page to refresh. There are about 100 different threads on this, and nothing I have tried has worked to resolve the issue. Out of curiosity, I just tried to run the window.location script and nothing else, and this piece actually doesn't work at all.

```php
<?php
//if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
//$ctstatus->nodeValue = $_POST['ctstatusform'];
//htmlentities($xml->save('test.xml'));
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="http://google.ca";</script>';
}
 ?>
```

The inner contents of the form don't really matter at this point, I just want it to refresh the page after I hit the submit button.

I previously used isset but from reading it seems like that's obsolete, and my form action="" used to be blank. Either way my XML save works, but nothing to refresh the page. I also tried header and that didn't work either.

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <input class="save" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
```

Out of curiosity I tried an onClick function with a timer and this does work but it's not ideal at all, especially because the page could technically refresh before the POST is finished writing the file. I'd rather know why the echo doesn't execute.

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the idea, but it doesn't return any errors at all.

Comment: What is happening with `myFunction()`?

Comment: That was something I forgot in the code when I was trying alternate methods to refresh the page. It did work but it was out of order because it refreshed before the submit went though. I pulled it and no change.

Comment: If you're submitting the page back to itself, why are you not just using php to redirect?  Typically you 1) check for submission, 2) if submission, do stuff and redirect, 3) if no submission show form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have gotten this sorted out. It turns out that the problem was embarrassingly simple, but maybe will assist someone in the future. Along with reordering my code, as Tim suggested. I specified HTML as the DOCTYPE, and that worked to resolve the issue. I no longer need to worry about refreshing the page after submit, because it refreshes as it should automatically. Thank you to everyone who commented.

Answer (score 1):

PHP redirect would most likely be preferable to JavaScript redirect.

Typical structure when posting back to same page:

```
<?php // cannot be any output before this (space, linefeed, etc)

if(isset($_POST['submit']) {

    // do stuff with the submission

    header('Location: http://google.ca');
    exit;
}

// does your script need to do some other data retrieval or calculation?  do it here.

?>
<html>
    ... snip ...
    <form method="post">
        ... snip ...
        <input class="save" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
```

Following this simple structure for procedural scripts--

1. Deal with user input / redirect
2. Do logic (collect, manipulate data)
3. Show output (using php only to insert variables and looping)

will help you avoid a lot of heartache and technical debt.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the advice on structure. Unfortunately I did already try this method with the header and it didn't work. I tried reordering everything as you suggested and it allowed me to see that there was another error, although unrelated.  Interestingly enough, it will redirect, albeit poorly, to the root index.html page if I specify it. It won't load anything else, even itself. No errors accompany.

Comment: That's weird.  Try knocking out all confounding factors by just putting the redirect as the very first thing (followed by exit or die) and see what happens.